# How to bring back the YSOD in asp.net if an error happens handling the error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

I have a custom error handler on my global.asax `Application_Error` message to handle all unhandled exceptions, including errors in the views, controllers, etc

This will in turn invoke the appropriate error controller providing the needed parameters that will display a proper error page.

However, this fails when the error controller throws an exception, leaving me with the decision about how to handle that (that happens usually when a breaking error is introduced in the site layout).

The current idea is to display the standard YSOD asp.net page displaying the source of the error (probably later on we'll switch to a fail safe html only error page, but for debugging purposes right now we want the YSOD).

So, is there any way to bring back that page if the error handling fails?

Notes:

1. We're invoking `Server.ClearError()`, if we don't we get the YOSD page but with the first error that ocurred, not the second one.
2. The exception itself can be captured and output to the screen via standard `Response.Write`, however I very much prefer to dump it via YOSD.

Edit: Code sample.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var exception = Server.GetLastError();
  LogWriter.LogException(exception);
  HttpContext.Current.Server.ClearError();

  GenerateErrorInfo(Title, HtmlDescription, exception);            
  IController controller = new ErrorController();
  var routeData = new RouteData();
  routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
  routeData.Values.Add("action", "Error");
  controller.Execute(new RequestContext(
        new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), 
        routeData)); <<-- Exception can happen here.
}

public static void GenerateErrorInfo(string Title, string HtmlDescription, Exception exception)
{
  HttpContext.Current.Application.Add("errorTitle", Title);
  HttpContext.Current.Application.Add("errorDescription", description);
}
```

Comment: could you show us what you're currently doing in a short code example?

Comment: put the error prone bit inside a try catch, and if you catch the error handle it there?

Comment: Yes, that's clear, but how do I get back the YOSD page. If I DON'T handle the error I'll get the yellow page, but once I've called the Server.ClearError that page is not displayed any more.

Comment: OH sorry my brain isnt with it today, gimme a sec XD

Comment: Instead of relying on this for debugging, why not log the error using ELMAH?